# Internet connection sharing issue Win7

Tags: internet, regedit, sharing

Ive been sharing my connection for years and suddenly it stopped working. Naturally I check the sharing tab and i get "network sharing disabled by administrator " ive gone through many answers on here with no success. I dont have gpedit.msc, Ive tried going to REGEDIT Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections,  but i don’t have "Network Connections" i feel like im missing something obvious

Comment: Your image is inaccessible you should use the upload image editor option

Comment: Try to [Turn On Network Discovery](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49652-turn-off-network-discovery-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: What questions have you gone through? What are the specific things you've tried?